# Calculate Quantity * Price = Total | Total / Price = Quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I need some help.

I want the **"Total"** to be calculated by the **"quantity * price = total"** (so far it's ok). The problem is that I also need **"Quantity"** to be calculated by **"total / price = quantity"** ie if one field is changed the other will automatically change.

I made a very simple example code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y830jhv/)

```
//Value of Price (Hidden)
$('#price').val(31245);

//Calculation
var qty=$("#qty");
qty.keyup(function(){
    var total=isNaN(parseInt(qty.val()* $("#price").val())) ? 0 :(qty.val()* $("#price").val())
    $("#total").val(total);
});
var total=$("#total");
total.keyup(function(){
    var qty=isNaN(parseInt(total.val()/ $("#price").val())) ? 0 :(total.val()/ $("#price").val())
    $("#qty").val(qty);
});

//Mask Total input
var originalVal = $.fn.val;

$.fn.val = function(value) {
    if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
        return originalVal.call(this);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.trigger('mask.maskMoney');
        }.bind(this), 100);
        return originalVal.call(this, value);
    }
};

$('#total').maskMoney();

$('#total').on('click mousedown mouseup focus blur keydown change input', function(event) {
    console.log('This Happened:'+ event.type);
});
```

In it the first part **"quantity * price = total"** works ok and is updated automatically. However, when in the second part **"total / price = quantity"** is the problem appears.

When the number entered in the Total input is too large (Example: 9,876.23) the quantity is not calculated automatically and returns 0. But if the number is for example 893.23 the quantity works as it should.

Could any of you help me? (sorry for my bad english)

**Ps:** I needed the value of the quantity field not to exceed 8 decimals (example: 0.00000000). But in all the attempts I had the calculation does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The thousands separator made automatically by the mask is not understood in the calculation, so you should remove it first from the input

```
var qty=isNaN(parseInt(total.val().replace(",", "")/ $("#price").val())) ? 0 :(total.val().replace(",", "")/ $("#price").val())
```

however, the problem will appear if more than one thousands separator appears (1,000,000), so you you can globally remove all thousands separators:

```
var my_total = total.val().replace(/,/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug this is to breakpoint the appropriate spot and see what's happening. For instance, in Chrome, pull up your Dev Tools, find the result panel, and set a breakpoint:

[image: Picture of JSFiddle at the appropriate spot]

Then, in the console, start evaluating parts of the expression. Here, I've evaluated `total.val()`. So what's happening?

The key thing to realize is that `total.val()` returns a **string**! So what happens when you use something like `"9,873.76"` as a number? That's right, JavaScript doesn't know what to do with the comma and punts, returning `NaN`.

Why did it show up when you had a number in the thousands? Because smaller numbers don't have commas.

So, as a result, you're getting zero.